# small pixel image as a background image for android app

Tags: android, image, background, styles

I have 4x4px image which i would like to set and repeat until it fills the full screen for all resolutions, when I set that image as a background it's being stretched.
I've added `android:tileMode="repeat"` to the main.xml to achive what i wanted but nothing is changed.

Final result should look like something like this

[image: Final result should look like something like this]

How can i do this ?

Comment: Instead of background set as src and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for me was to create a separate drawable and use it in layout file

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/my_img"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set the scale type to of the image at start and then add repeat mode:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Nine-patch image using android nine-patch tool.

[You can create on-line](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

or

You can create off-line also

Under ==> sdk/tools/draw9patch

Double click and run this file

hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
//Repeating background image
Bitmap backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   R.drawable.my_background_image);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), backgroundImage);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  
view.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```